# Power law correction factor in tree enumeration via naïve division

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, trees

It is a theorem of Otter, building on fundamental work of Pólya, that the number of unlabeled trees on $n$ vertices is $\approx C \alpha^{n} n^{-5/2}$, where $C = 0.534\ldots$ and $\alpha = 2.955\ldots$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Unlabeled_trees).

A naïve way to count unlabeled trees on $n$ vertices would be to take Cayley's formula for the number of labeled trees, $n^{n-2}$, and divide by $n!$ (this would be like assuming that every tree has a trivial automorphism group, which is of course not true). By Stirling's approximation, $n^{n-2}/n! \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{n}n^{-5/2}$, so we definitely do not get even approximately the right answer this way. However, the "power law correction" factor of $n^{-5/2}$ is still oddly correct.

**Question**: Is there a high level explanation for why this naïve division gives the "correct" factor of $n^{-5/2}$?

EDIT: The same factor of $n^{-5/2}$ apparently arises in the related enumeration of unlabeled outerplanar graphs (see https://doi.org/10.37236/984). I would be interested in some discussion of if this factor is a "universal power law correction" (as in e.g. self-avoiding walks in a given dimension - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk#Universality).

EDIT 2: I think this phenomenon is discussed in the paper "Universal singular exponents in catalytic variable equations" by Michael Drmota and Marc Noy and Guan-Ru Yu (https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.07103).

Comment: The ratio between Otter's formula and the naive count should be the size of the automorphism group of the typical tree. I wonder if we can prove something about the structure of such automorphism groups .

Comment: From the statistical physics/probability point of view, the coincidence of the $n^{-5/2}$ reflects that uniform unlabeled trees and uniform labeled trees live in the same universality class as random metric spaces, namely that of Aldous' Continuum Random Tree (CRT). See [Stufler, "The continuum random tree is the scaling limit of unlabeled unrooted trees"](https://doi.org/10.1002/rsa.20833) for the unlabeled case. The exponent $-5/2$ is related to the scaling of the Brownian excursion encoding a CRT.